# String ресурс в Int?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть объект в конструкторе котогорого заголовок типа Int, но сейчас понадобилось захардкодить просто строковый ресурс типа : "some" как можно захардкодить так, чтоб не менять параметры класса?

На данный момент код такой

```
class LinkItem(val titleId: Int) {

override fun equals(other: Any?) = other?.javaClass == javaClass && titleId == (other as LinkItem).titleId

override fun hashCode() = titleId

constructor(titleId: String) : this()
}
```

Но подчеркивает во втором конструкторе this

Comment: Захардкодить "some" в strings.xml. Иначе никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте конструктор в Вашем классе с параметром String. Тогда Вы сможете передавать параметры как Int так и String. [Примеры](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) как это делается.

**UPD:**
Для Вашего случая это будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
class LinkItem(val titleId: Int) {
constructor(title: String) : this(title.hashCode())

override fun equals(other: Any?) = other?.javaClass == javaClass && titleId == (other as LinkItem).titleId

override fun hashCode() = titleId
}
```

Конструктор, который объявлен сразу после имени класса - является главным. Если есть главный конструктор, дополнительные конструкторы должны всегда его вызывать.

Аргументы во второстепенном могут быть любые, или вообще без них, главное при этом вызвать главный и передать необходимые для главного конструктора аргументы (а как именно - это зависит от задачи)